# Unable to find element with xpath for Add -ons text (Correct xpath)

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);       
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);         
driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com");  
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add-Ons')]")))
      .build().perform();       
Thread.sleep(3000);     
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Hot Meals ")).click();      
driver.close();
```

Unable to locate element with xpath  `//a[contains(text(),'Add-Ons')`

Its it regarding frames?

Comment: Add HTML code for reference, Where and how it is located

Comment: It seem that required drop-down menu appears only in full-screen mode, so to make your code work, check whether you use `driver.manage().window().maximize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xpath can find the correct element when I verify it by manual. I suspect the page not load completely, please add some `sleep` after `dirver.get()` for debug purpose.

```
driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com"); 

Thread.sleep(10*1000) // sleep 10 seconds to wait page open completely.

Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add-Ons')]")))
      .build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes exact element can't be found using `By.linkText()`

You just use `cssSelector` like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#header-addons > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

instead of the line `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Hot Meals ")).click();`

You can also use `xpath` instead like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"header-addons\"]/ul/li[5]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: @Chinmay I ran the code using chrome in my pc. your code is almost right and running fine if you use `cssSelector` instead of `linkText`. It would be good if you use about 5/6 sec sleep after `driver.get()` method.

Comment: @Chinmay please accept the answer if it is really helpful for you.

Comment: *Sometimes exact element can't be found using By.linkText()*... Can you explain this "Sometimes"? AFAIK it works always!

Comment: Also note that the problem is in `By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add-Ons')]")`, but not in `By.linkText("Hot Meals ")`, so your solution is useless

Comment: @Andersson I ran this successfully. Would you like to get a video screen?   I don't post any answer without ensuring. How do you say the solution is useless thus for down-voting it?

Comment: Your suggestion is to replace line for clicking option while OP need a solution for locating drop-down on previous lines. Also your claim about locating elements by link text is unclear/misleading. Add some clarifications for the same

Comment: @Andersson different browser behaves differently. `linkText` doesn't provide good result in some cases.